# PDF Attachments breaks Signatur of Attachment

Tags: pdf, certificate, itext, adobe, acrobat

First I want to describe my task briefly so we are on the same page:
I have multiple PDF Files that must be combined to one File. Some of them are Signed Documents, where the Signature is made with Adobe X Standard and PKI Certificate.
For the signed PDFs I choose to add them as an attachment in the main PDF as adding them as new pages to the main PDF would break the signature, because the hash for the Signature would not be the same as all changes are permitted by signing an Document.

I tried two approches to combine them, the first was mit Adobe X Standard and the second with an Java Application which uses iText5. Both worked and generated an PDF with those files attached.

When I open that combined PDF with Adobe X Standard (either created with Adobe or iText) and then try to open the attached PDFs with the signatures, it says that the signature could not be authenticated. But when I save the attached PDF then the authentification is suddenly working.

I read about PDFs and signatures both in the whitepaper from iText and also in the ISO standard but I can't figure out, why the signature is broken in the first attempt but correct when the file is saved on disk. So if somebody could clarify this for me that would be great.

I also have uploaded an example file to https://www.docdroid.net/mTuUAIn/testattachment.pdf.html so you could see it for your self.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What application is doing the signing? What application is doing the attaching?

Comment: Please share an example file to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Hello, the signing is done with Adobe X Standard, and the attaching is also done by it but I also tried it with iText.

Here is an example: http://docdro.id/mTuUAIn 
If I open the Files in Adobe X it says that the Signature is broken, if I copy them i.e. to my Desktop then the validation is working.

Comment: I don't have Adobe Acrobat X here, merely Adobe Acrobat 9.5 and Adobe Reader DC. In neither case I was told the signature is *broken*. Before getting any green marks, though, I had to trust the certificate in question. Now  Adobe Reader DC immediately shows green marks / certification banners while Adobe Acrobat 9.5 first says that the signature requires validation. When I ask it to validate it shows that a "Novartis Signing" plug-in has been used to create the signature. I don't have that plug-in installed, so I select Adobe Default Security, and I get green marks.

Comment: So causes for the issue you observe I can think of are (A) an issue of the very Adobe X version you use or (B) (if you happen to have that 'Novartis Signing' plug-in installed which in particular in your case is not improbable) an issue of the 'Novartis Signing' plug-in.

Comment: Thank you for testing this, well as I'm neither capable to change Adobe X nor the Novartis Signing plug-in, I will have to cope with it. I thought maybe I was miss interpreting the feature of attachments but as that's not the case I can continue with my work. If I'm able to figure out either it's Adobe X or the Novartis Signing plugin I will come back and clarify that.